# R parallel programming foreach doubts

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am using parallel processing to pass the variable 'marker' to a z_vector. But the problem is it is not going through all the values in 'markers' and repeating many values.

```
library("parallel"); 
library("doParallel"); 
library("foreach");

markers=1:100
c=makeCluster(detectCores()-4);
registerDoParallel(c,cores=detectCores()-4); ##Using 3 out of 4 cores

k=0;

z_vector = foreach (j = 1:100,.combine=c) %dopar%
{
 k=k+1;
 marker=markers[k]
 marker
}
```

But when I output the z_vector, I get this

```
z_vector
  [1]  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9
 [20] 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19
 [39] 19 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27 28 28
 [58] 29 29 30 30 31 31 32 32 33 33 34 34 35 35 36 36 37 37 38
 [77] 38  2 39 39 40 40 41 41 42 42 43 43 44 44 45 45 46 47 46
 [96] 48 47 49 48 50
```

I have tried on Windows (using 3 cores) where I get 3 repetitions of '1' and Linux (using 20 cores) where I get 20 repetitions of '1'. How can I make the foreach loop pass through exactly 1 to 100 without repetitions? And why are these repetitions happening at the first place? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any other way to implement the code so I get the correct output? If you have encountered similar issues, kindly bring them for discussion too.

Comment: It is not a bug, it's a feature. The jobs do not share the variable `k` and thus have separate counters, not one. The obvious fix would be to use `j` instead of `k` and not increase it manually.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. However, many a times R doesn't allow you to use the variable in the foreach call.

Comment: That is a caveat you have to find a work around for. This is probably why I do not use `foreach`. I prefer old classic loops and I extract the relevant data using the loop variable `j`.

Comment: The iterator of a `foreach` loop is specified as the first parameter. That's basically the same as with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a loop to be executed in parallel, each iteration must be independent of every other. You can't use operations such `k=k+1` in a parallel loop, since it depends on a value of "k" computed in a previous iteration.

In this case, you can simply iterate over "markers" using:

```
z_vector = foreach(marker=markers, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  marker
}
```

This removes the loop dependency, and may also be more efficient since "markers" doesn't have to be exported to all of the workers. This is particularly important when iterating over columns of a matrix, for example.